# NSTokenField: different colors for tokens

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstokenfield, nstokenfieldcell

I have created an NSTokenField in my xib. I'd like to display tokens with different colors inside that tokenField. Meaning: some tokens will be blue, the rest will be red (according to their content). Is that possible?

The following code doesn't work for me. I hope someone can help me out:

```
- (id)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField representedObjectForEditingString:(NSString *)editingString
{
    id returnRepresentedObject = nil;

    NSTokenFieldCell *tf = [[NSTokenFieldCell alloc] init];
    tf.stringValue = editingString;
    tf.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor];
    returnRepresentedObject = tf;

    return returnRepresentedObject;
}
```

Result: all tokens remain blue... :-(

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Its possible by using private APIs. Subclass `NSTokenAttachmentCell` (Private) and `NSTokenFieldCell`.

[Sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7gx5nvkff1ivtqj/TokenField.zip)

[image]

Use BWTokenAttachmentCell and [BWTokenFieldCell](https://bitbucket.org/bwalkin/bwtoolkit/src/tip/BWTokenFieldCell.m) class and [NSTokenAttachmentCell](https://bitbucket.org/bwalkin/bwtoolkit/src/tip/NSTokenAttachmentCell.h) class dump from BWToolkit. Modify initialize method of [BWTokenAttachmentCell](https://bitbucket.org/bwalkin/bwtoolkit/src/tip/BWTokenAttachmentCell.m).

[sample project

**NOTE:**

Use this method if you are not targeting for  Mac App Store.

Comment: Thanks @Parag, however I was wondering how to color different cells with different colors: first one in blue, second one in red, etc. I will clarify my original question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to role your own. There is a wwdc video from 2010 about advanced Cocoa Text handling. The NSTokenField Uses NSTextAttachments to render the tokens.